# Tsqlt tests are failing even though Expected and Actual tables have same values

Tags: sql-server, tsqlt

I am getting error  failed: (Failure) Unexpected/missing resultset rows! for tsqlt tests even though Expected and Actual table has same result

| volume | 90Dayvolume | Relative90Dvol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4493 | 16413368.1429 | 95.119153740058 |

In above example "Relative90Dvol" is being calculated with in stored procedure.If Relative90Dvol is a integer value say 95 the tests are being passed but if value is in float with decimal precision like  95.119153740058 tests are failing.
How to handle such decimal precision values with tsqlt tests.

```
failed: (Failure) Unexpected/missing resultset rows!
|_m_|symbol |exchange|session|Time                |Open   | Volume             |Volume.90D          |Relative90D.Pct             |insert_Date         |
+---+-------+--------+-------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+---------+----------------------------+--------------------+
|<  |TEST1.O|NSQ     |0      |4.479070000000000E+4|!NULL! |1.292000000000000E+3|6.923157219780000E+6|8.635296985604490E+1        |4.479070000000000E+4|
|<  |TEST2.O|NSQ     |0      |4.479070000000000E+4|!NULL! |2.229000000000000E+3|9.369240538460000E+6|1.100841107726760E+2        |4.479070000000000E+4|
|>  |TEST2.O|NSQ     |0      |4.479070000000000E+4|!NULL! |2.229000000000000E+3|9.369240538460000E+6|1.100841107726760E+2        |4.479070000000000E+4|
|>  |TEST1.O|NSQ     |0      |4.479070000000000E+4|!NULL! |1.292000000000000E+3|6.923157219780000E+6|8.635296985604490E+1        |4.479070000000000E+4|
```

Comment: If the tests are failing, expected and actual tables do not have the same values.  Update your question with the table schema and expected / actual values that tSQLt is throwing a failure for.  Showing the test code and the code that calculates `Relative90Dvol` would help also.

Comment: When comparing floating point values it is usual to have an epsilon value rather than demanding strict equality. Possibly AssertTableEquals does not have a way of doing this and you will need to find a workaround though https://github.com/tSQLt-org/tSQLt/issues/33

Comment: Floats, being approximate numeric types, are always problematic. Have you tried selecting your data-under-test into `#Expected` and `#Actual` temp tables while casting the floats to decimals with specific precision and scale?

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning , Yes I think in this way I can have solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I usually end up implementing some *tolerance*. You can do that easily in the following manner:

```
declare @actual decimal(30,2);
declare @expected decimal(30,2) = 789.5;
declare @tolerance decimal(18,2) = 0.1;

IF @actual between @expected - @tolerance and @expected + @tolerance 
    set @actual = @expected;

EXEC tsqlt.AssertEquals @expected, @actual, @Message = '...';
```